# About free modules and finitely generated modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Module theory was covered in our class in only two lectures and I am not comfortable in solving problems of modules. This is one such question.  Can someone help with a detailed argument. 
Question is:

> Show that every finitely generated module is a homomorphic image of a free module.

Comment: Actually, every $R$-module is a homomorphic image of a free module.

Comment: Can you please tell how to write rigorously.  Intution is also clear to me.